# What are some of malware-based MITM attacks that can compromise the organization when working remotely?

Tags: malware, man-in-the-middle, virus

With the Coronavirus happening, employees use remote access to work remotely from not organizational laptop access to their VDI or remote access machine via company's web portal (e.g. SSL Portal VPN). I was wondering if the laptop is infected with malware, what are some of the malware-based MITM attacks that compromise the organization when working remotely?

Answer (score 3):

I understand your security concerns with the use of non-work (hence non-controlled and not secured by your habitual standards).

I don't believe that there are any sort of malware that could possibly, via a MiTM attack, compromise the organizations security as long as they are using SSL.
Albeit if we look outside of the MiTM type attacks, there are, as you surely know, multiple attacks that could compromise your work VDEs given that they could emulate your user's access. A simple keylogger could permit an attacker to access a certain user's VDE giving them multiple attack opportunities if the VDIs permissions are not configured correctly.

Just to summarize, I don't believe MiTM is in the threat model for this type of operation albeit other sorts of attacks could allow a perpetrator to access your VDEs so they should be properly configured permission-wise and you should always be cautious of what sort of data you store/allow access to on the VDE.

Comment: @Filipon Cert injection, valid point, but the malware would have to compromise the VDE access software too, most of them, from what I know, don't rely on the PCs trusted CA list and use their own one

Comment: If you want you could check out this question, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91001/protect-ssl-connections-from-mitm-for-users-with-modified-clients?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I understood, but the devices that your employees are using to connect to the VDE are their personal computers, correct? Those are the ones that could possibly be infected

Comment: That's what I meant when I said "non-work". If you have any more queries don't hesitate do start a chat I'll be happy to help there. I'm just saying since we should avoid long discussions in chat.